# How do I 'cat' a text file but start from the bottom instead of top

Tags: text-processing, cat

I have a very big text log file of about 37MB.
Using `cat file | more` I can view the file contents one page at a time.

The problem is that this always starts from the top - the old entries.
How can I make it start from the bottom where the newer entries are then move up page by page?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try the [`tac`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tac.1) command, which reverses the input, line by line.

Alternatively, [`less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/less.1) is `more`. Start at the end of the file using `+G`:

```
less +G some-file
```

You might have to get used to pressing <kbd>b</kbd> (which jumps back a screen) instead of <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: `tac` starts at the bottom but I can't get a way to go up a screen. `less some-file +G` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Parto go up a screen in what? As for +G, open the file in less, then press Shift-G. Does it go to the end of the file?

Comment: @Parto apparently less doesn't follow the Vim convention of allowing commands after filenames even though it borrows key strokes from it. Try `less +G some-file`.

Comment: `less +G` seems more natural when viewing command line history, for example. Something like this: `alias h='history -999999 | less +G'`